# Saved job search emails sending to my old email

Tags: support, status-completed, email, stack-overflow-jobs

I've changed & confirmed the email address in my Stack Overflow account which -as the settings page states- is affecting my other Stack Exchange services (askubuntu, superuser, unix etc.), but I still get saved job search emails in my old email address and not the new one.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a glitch in a background process that syncs your information to the system that handles `/jobs` things like alert emails. I’ve just kicked it and it looks like your email address has been synced correctly.